# Grok for jrockit gc logging

Tags: elasticsearch, garbage-collection, logstash, kibana, grok

I have the below jrockit gc log which I want to index using grok to find pattern.

> [memory ][Thu Feb  4 14:23:21 2016][01888] [OC#1119] 199979.563-199981.320: OC 1875383KB->1445390KB (2097152KB), 1.757 s, sum of pauses 1731.731 ms, longest pause 1731.731 ms.

The Information I want is

```
date : Thu Feb  4 14:23:21 2016
CurrentHeap: 1875383
Heap: 1445390
TotalHeap: 2097152
SumofPause: 1731.731
LongestPause: 1731.731
```

I starte writing something like this..

> [memory ][%{DATA:wls_timestamp}][%{DATA:discard1}][%{DATA:discard2}]

But couldn't go any further, can someone guide me how to extract specific information in a data like this.

Thanks
SR

Comment: You don't describe why you had to stop, but please note that brackets are characters used in regular expressions and typically need to be escaped to work.  Try "\[" at least.

Comment: Check out some of the other built-in patterns other than DATA.  For your date, there may not be a pattern that matches your whole field, but building it up from %DAY (etc) will make it more clear to anyone who needs to maintain it.